# Exporting gridview to Excel. Why do some columns with numeric data align to right and some to left? How do I get them all to align to the left?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, export, alignment, export-to-excel

When exporting a gridview to Excel, I can't figure out how to "force" the columns to all left align.  Some seem to do this automatically, while other fields in columns will align to the right. (the column is all numeric)  What did I do wrong, or forget to do?

**my buton from my .aspx**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="30px" ImageUrl="~/images/Logo.jpg" OnClick="Button1_Click" Width="28px" />
```

**My Code behind**

```
private void ExportToExcel(string strFileName, GridView dg) 
    { 
        Response.Clear(); 
        Response.Buffer = true; 
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; 
        Response.Charset = ""; 
        this.EnableViewState = false; 
        System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(); 
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter); 
        GridView1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter); 
        Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString()); 
        Response.End(); 
    } 
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        ExportToExcel("Test.xls", GridView1); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is Excel that is interpreting the data and deciding which alignment to use rather than your code. If the values are all numeric, I'd expect them all to be right aligned by default. The ones that are left aligned are probably being interpreted as text and quite possibly include white space or another character that causes Excel to see it as text.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Evert about excel interpreting the data.   I've noticed that if the number is 80-1245 it will align to the left.  If the number is 801245, it will align to the right.  Added an  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" /> tag on each field in the grid view, and now when it exports to excel, they all align to the left.   :-)